# Making selectizeInput reactive to show/hide markers on Leaflet Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, reactive, leaflet.markercluster

I am in the process of making a map of street food in Oaxaca, Mexico, although I am running into some trouble. I am trying to produce a leaflet map in Shiny and understand the UI side of shiny, although the server side not as much. I understand that I have to add either observe() or reactive() to the server side to produce the desired results, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I included addlayercontrol() to the leaflet as this effect is desired (hide and show markers based on what is selected) although I would like the selectizeImput to control the layers. Below is my code, I included a small subset of the dataset, as well as some commented out code of what I tried on the server side. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

#Data Sample

long <- c(-96.72363, -96.72880, -96.72700)
lat <- c(17.06167, 17.06200, 17.06170 )
name <- c("jim", "grant", "pablo")
food <- c("tacos", "burger", "elote")


df <- data.frame(long, lat, name, food)

#subsets

palette<- colorFactor(palette = c("blue", "green", "black"),
                      domain = df$food)
tacos <- dplyr::filter(df, grepl("tacos", food))

burger <- dplyr::filter(df, grepl("burger", food))

elote <- dplyr::filter(df, grepl("elote", food))


#ui 


ui <-fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = "Street Food Oaxaca"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("food","Select a Type:",
                  choices = unique(df$food),
                  selected = ,
                  multiple = TRUE)),
    mainPanel(h3("Map"), leafletOutput("m", width = "800", height = "600"))
  )
)

#server
server <- function(input, output, session){ 
    output$m = renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = df) %>%
      setView(lng = -96.725, lat = 17.0618, zoom =14)%>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers( layerId = tacos,
                          data = tacos,
                          ~long,
                          ~lat,
                          group = 'tacos',
                          popup = ~as.character(name),
                          radius = 2,
                          color =  ~palette(food),
                          fillOpacity = 0.5) %>%
        addCircleMarkers( layerId = burger,
                          data = burger,
                          ~long,
                          ~lat,
                          group = 'burger',
                          popup = ~as.character(name),
                          radius = 2,
                          color =  ~palette(food),
                          fillOpacity = 0.5) %>%
        addCircleMarkers( layerId = elote,
                          data = elote,
                          ~long,
                          ~lat,
                          group = 'elote',
                          popup = ~as.character(name),
                          radius = 2,
                          color =  ~palette(food),
                          fillOpacity = 0.5) %>%
        # addPolygons(data = poly,
        #           ~long,
        #           ~lat,
        #           weight = 3,
        #           color = "red",
        #           group = "Restricted Zone" ,
        #           popup = "Restricted Zone")
      addLayersControl(
        overlayGroups = c("tacos","burger","elote", "Restricted Zone"),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE)
      )


    })
}    
      
      
      #  observeEvent(
      # if(function(input$food, value ="tacos"))
      #   output$m = renderLeaflet('m')%>%
      #    removeMarker(layerId = m,c('burger', 'elote')))
                               
      #removeMarker(group == C('two', 'three'))

      # data_f <- reactive({
      #   dplyr::filter(df$food == "tacos")
      # })
      # 
      # observeEvent(data_f, {
      # 
      #   leafletProxy("map") %>%
      # 
      #     clearMarkers() }) 
    
         

  


 #Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

#Data Sample

long <- c(-96.72363, -96.72880, -96.72700)
lat <- c(17.06167, 17.06200, 17.06170 )
name <- c("jim", "grant", "pablo")
food <- c("tacos", "burger", "elote")


df <- data.frame(long, lat, name, food)

#subsets

palette <- colorFactor(palette = c("blue", "green", "black"),
                      domain = df$food)
tacos <- dplyr::filter(df, grepl("tacos", food))

burger <- dplyr::filter(df, grepl("burger", food))

elote <- dplyr::filter(df, grepl("elote", food))

ui <-fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = "Street Food Oaxaca"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("food","Select a Type:",
                     choices = unique(df$food),
                     selected = food[1],
                     multiple = TRUE)),
    mainPanel(h3("Map"), leafletOutput("m", width = "800", height = "600"))
  )
)

#server
server <- function(input, output, session){ 
  
  df1 <- eventReactive(input$food, {
    df %>% dplyr::filter(food %in% input$food)
  })
  
  output$m = renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = df1()) %>%
      setView(lng = -96.725, lat = 17.0618, zoom =14)%>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers( # layerId = input$food,
                        # data = input$food,
                        ~long,
                        ~lat,
                        #group = input$food,
                        #popup = ~as.character(name),
                        radius = 2,
                        color =  ~palette(input$food),
                        fillOpacity = 0.5) %>%
      # addCircleMarkers( layerId = burger,
      #                   data = burger,
      #                   ~long,
      #                   ~lat,
      #                   group = 'burger',
      #                   popup = ~as.character(name),
      #                   radius = 2,
      #                   color =  ~palette(food),
      #                   fillOpacity = 0.5) %>%
      # addCircleMarkers( layerId = elote,
      #                   data = elote,
      #                   ~long,
      #                   ~lat,
      #                   group = 'elote',
      #                   popup = ~as.character(name),
      #                   radius = 2,
      #                   color =  ~palette(food),
      #                   fillOpacity = 0.5) %>%
      # addPolygons(data = poly,
      #           ~long,
      #           ~lat,
      #           weight = 3,
      #           color = "red",
      #           group = "Restricted Zone" ,
      #           popup = "Restricted Zone")
      addLayersControl(
        overlayGroups = c("tacos","burger","elote", "Restricted Zone"),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE)
      )
    
    
  })
}    

#Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @YBS. This code does produce more of the desired output, but I would like the map to show up upon opening the app. With your code, there is no map until you click on the options, at which point the map shows up with the right markers. What would I have to add for the map to show up before clicking one of the options? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try the updated code. You just need to specify what you want in `selected = ` in the `selectInput`.